# Android: Swipe Views without additional support library

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-support-library

I have no interest in backward support for < 4.0 devices. And also, I would like to get rid of support libraries to make package as small as possible.

Is it possible to create similar effect only using 4.0+ native fragments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ViewPager` is not tied to any fragments. You are welcome to use `ViewPager` with:

- the fragment backport, or
- native API Level 11+ fragments, or
- no fragments at all, using `Views` for the pages

You are also welcome to copy [the source code to `ViewPager`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.java) and [`PagerAdapter`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.java) into your project. If you would like to use `FragmentPagerAdapter` or `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` with native API Level 11+ fragments, you can copy [the source code to the `v13` editions of those classes](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v13/java/android/support/v13/app) into your project as well.